# Is there a way to get the Microsoft Office Version and it's License installed on the Computer?

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am trying to get the specifications of my PC. This system is used to monitor the installed Office and License on the Computer. I have to search for it on the internet but I have seen nothing. I am using c#.

Can someone help me with this, Thank you and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                Arguments = "/C reg query \"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\Word.Application\\CurVer\""
            };


            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);

            string version = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(output, "(.*)(Word\\.Application\\.)(\\d+)(.*)", "$3", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline);
            Console.WriteLine("Office version: " + version);

            Console.Read();
```

Office 97   -  7

Office 98   -  8

Office 2000 -  9

Office XP   - 10

Office 2003 - 11

Office 2007 - 12

Office 2010 - 14

Office 2013 - 15

Office 2016 - 16

Comment: I have tried it sir, But the return value is 12, but my office version is 7.

Comment: It is right. If the version of Office is 2007, returns 12. See it Office 97   -  7
Office 98   -  8
Office 2000 -  9
Office XP   - 10
Office 2003 - 11
Office 2007 - 12
Office 2010 - 14 
Office 2013 - 15
Office 2016 - 16

Comment: Ahh.. Okay sir. Thank you. That's It. God Bless HAHA